# Draw Circle is inaccurate

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

In my app, when the user touches the screen, a circle is drawn, and if a circle has already been drawn at point a, then another circle cannot be drawn there.

when I use canvas.drawCircle(...), it's innacurate. if I tap close to the top of the screen, then it is just very minutely missing where I tapped it (slightly to the left or right). The farther I go down the farther up my circle is from where I touched. If I'm touching the left side of the screen, the circle goes to the right of the touch point, and if I touch the right side of the screen, the circle is on the left.

Here's my code:

```
public void onCreate(...){
   super.onCreate();
   setcontentView(...);
    drawnX = new ArrayList<Float>();
    drawnY = new ArrayList<Float>();

    layout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
            newY = me.getY();
            newX = me.getX();
            int action = me.getAction();

            if (action==0){
                Log.v(tag, "New Touch");
                Log.i(tag, String.valueOf("Action " + action +
                        " happened at X,Y: " + "("+newX+","+newY + ")"));
                getDistance(newX, newY);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
     display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     screenHeight = display.getHeight();
     screenWidth = display.getWidth();

     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
     paint = new Paint();
     circleRadius = screenHeight/50;
}
public void getDistance(float xNew, float yNew){
     // here I compare the new touch x and y values with the x and y values saved
     // in the Array Lists I made above. If distance is > circleRadius, then: 
drawPoint(xNew, yNew)
}
public void drawPoint(final float x, final float y){
    minDistance = Float.NaN;


    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, circleRadius, paint);
            layout.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    layout.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
//I have also tried setImageBitmap and setBackgroundDrawable
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


}
```

Int the process of all of this, I also do some logging in the drawPoint, and it shows that the x and y coordinates match that which are gotten in the onTouch.

I've also tried maknig it a LinearLayout, but that had the same effect.

And, the bitmap size matches the screen size and canvas size. also, for testing I did

```
canvas.drawARGB(...)
```

and it covered the whole screen, so I know it's not just that the bitmap is not stretching to the bottom. The layout's height is less than the height of everything else, and the width of the layout is the same as everything else, but when I use layout.getHeight and layout.getWidth in my onResume, they always return 0, so I can't really use that.

I really have no clue what's causing it. I also tried it on two emulators and got the same response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if I tap on the drawn circle (toward the bottom of the screen), another circle will then be drawn above that one, but if I tap where I previously tapped, then a new circle will not be drawn, which really is what's suppose to happen. the circle is just not showing on the screen correctly.

Comment: When I fixed the screenHeight and screenWidth to actually be layout.getHeight() and layout.getWidth(), that resolved the problem. I had to wrap that in new handler().postDelayed(runnable, 5000) to return a value for them, though. I will post full answer after the 8 hour posting time frame has passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Oddly enough, even though the width of the bitmap matched the width of the layout, when I did a little more testing, I found the dimensions didn't actually fit together on the left and right either.

I wasn't using the layout.getWidth() and layout.getHeight() due to it returning 0 in onResume()

But, I thought the different height from display.getHeight() very well may be causing the problem, so I did essentially:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(getLayoutSizeRunnable, 5000);
```

where getLayoutSizeRunnable was essentially:

```
screenWidth = layout.getWidth();
screenHeight = layout.getHeight();
```

Then everything worked perfectly.

And for the usage in my app, I'll use an if statement so the first time a touch point is made, the layout size will be calculated, and the bitmap will be created based on it.